# How to use two Source Code Block side by side in the same file

Tags: org-mode

So, as the question suggest, what i want is to use two different source code block, *side by side* on the same file. Something like this:

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC shell         #+BEGIN_SRC shell
ls /mnt/                  echo "hello"
#+END_SRC                 #+END_SRC
```

I need them to be like this mostly for understanding/comparing some output from commands, and while I'm sure it's easier to achieve this by using org-mode and rendering the source code block side by side, in the rendered documents *instead*, i prefer not doing so.

I also did try using two window side by side with two different files, but i really prefer if everything is on the same file.

Typically, i need the result to be on the same level as the source code block:

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC shell         #+BEGIN_SRC shell
ls /mnt/                  echo "hello"
#+END_SRC                 #+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:                #+RESULTS:
| folder1 |               | hello |
| folder2 |
```

I used *space* as delimiter between the two block, but i don't mind if it's any other delimiter (like tab).

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. You'd need to rewrite the whole of babel.

Comment: @nickd Does babel not "nest" in latex? Which of course has such possibilities I think?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "nesting in latex". How does LaTeX enter in the scenario above?

Comment: @NickD : I'm suggesting that the org source as written won't work (as are you). I'm also conjecturing that if the arc blocks are put one after the other and embedded within @@html with suitable css included the html export can be made to show as OP wants. (I know about zero of html/css and less about latex  ... so treat my conjectures with appropriate quantities of salt)

Comment: That might be possible indeed, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @nickd wonder if op just wants ediff?

Comment: already mentioned in my post that *I'm fully aware it can be done in a rendered output* (be it in latex, html, pdf...) but that this isn't what i want :) (what i want is to do it directly in org-mode in the same file/buffer, like the example in my post) @Rusi

Comment: is it really needed to "rewrite" babel for this? I wouldn't be surprised if there an easier way...(even if it's an hack/non-recommended method) @NickD

Comment: E.g. Org mode recognizes `#+BEGIN_SRC:` at the beginning of the line (with optional whitespace in front). Now there are two of them on the same line, so that logic has to change. You'll also have to decide which part of the code below belongs to the LHS block and which to the RHS block. "Rewrite" is not too strong a work IMO.